# Regarding Yii alignment of gridview

Tags: php, css, yii

[image]

Is that possible to make alignment for grid view? As you see the picture above, the checkbox are out of the boxes. I think column should be need add something. Below is my part of the code:

```
                        'columns'=>array(
                        array(
                            'name' => 'id',
                            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                            'selectableRows' => '99',
                            'checked' => 'true',  
                            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center'),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name' => 'edesc',
                            'header' => 'School Type',
                            'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:left')
                        ),
```

Comment: CCheckBox  is fo Yii1 ... (inconsistent tag removed)

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding a proper style width for checkbox column (and for the edesc column)

```
        array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
                'selectableRows' => '99',
                'checked' => 'true',  
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center; width: 10%;'),
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'edesc',
                'header' => 'School Type',
                'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:left; width: 90%;')
            ),
```